# execute code just when install the application using installshield

Tags: c#, registry, installshield

I am just wondering if it is possible to run a small code just once when the application is installing.

I would like to create a registry with the installation path. The reason why I need that because I have a windows service in my application as well, which install path always changes to system32.

I have an ini file which is created in the installation folder at installation. I need to reach that file with my service and windows form as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any extra code, just create a registry key in HKLM\software\yoursoftware-here with a key name like Installpath and a value of [INSTALLDIR] in your install, then reference that key in your service.

This assumes you are using a basic MSI project in install shield.

Comment: Hi @NGaida , sorry for the late reply I was a bit busy. How should  create that registry in install shield? Should I go to Project Assistant/Application Registry/(on the left side) Other Places/Registry then Destination computer's registry view tree view? Is this the right place to insert the registry key?

Comment: Are you using Installshield to create Basic MSI setups or Installscript setups?

Comment: Oh yeah, I have the LE version, I do not know if that makes any difference.

Comment: That actually matters a lot. I don't think LE will edit or output MSI installers; hence my answer won't do you much good. I've not used the LE product at all.

Comment: At least I know why i did not find the option what you mentioned:P Thank you anyway